# Why does only my second if statement give results and overrides my first if statement?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I was building a scraper for IMDB and came across an issue. It's not as technical, however, seems more conceptual. I have attached my code below. So what I was trying to figure out was why only the 2nd if statement runs? Whenever I run the program, my array(Metascore) gets filled with the values from the second if statement only. Note: Both if statements do run but only the values of the second one fill the array.

I think it might have something to do with the .find() but I could not figure out an explanation. I have also attached an image that shows the structure of the HTML I am trying to scrape. The website link is: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_1000&ref_=adv_prv.

The last image shows the code results.

If anyone has a solution or a thought, drop it below. Thanks.

```
  $('.ratings-bar').each((i, el) => {

    if($(el).find('.ratings-metascore .favorable')){
      metascore[i] = $(el).find('.ratings-metascore .favorable').text().trim();
    }

    if($(el).find('.ratings-metascore .mixed')){
      metascore[i] = $(el).find('.ratings-metascore .mixed').text().trim();
    }
  })

  console.log(metascore);
```

[image]

[image: The results after running that piece of code]

Comment: are you sue only the second statement runs, and its not the issue with second statement just running right after the first one and overriding the metascore value? they are both assigning values to the same field

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Both if statements do run, however, the results for the second one are printed out only.

Comment: I think it should not be overriding the answer because, if the first, if statement is not run it, would go to the second one and the array would be filled at that 'i' position.

Comment: it would go to the second statement either way, not matter if the first one was successful or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `$(el).find('.ratings-metascore .favorable').text()` actually return '' an empty string even tho there is no element found, so each time the `$(el).find('.ratings-metascore > .mixed').text()` is overriding the result of `metascore[i]` of `$(el).find('.ratings-metascore .favorable').text()` with an empty string.

just comment out the

```js
if($(el).find('.ratings-metascore .mixed')){
   metascore[i] = $(el).find('.ratings-metascore .mixed').text().trim();
}
```

and you will see your `.favorable` results

---

**Updated**

Since both of the conditions returns true, because the `find()` returns always an Object, you have to add `.length > 0` to your if conditions to make it work properly

```js
 $('.ratings-bar').each((i, el) => {

    if($(el).find('.ratings-metascore .favorable').length > 0){
      metascore[i] = $(el).find('.ratings-metascore .favorable').text().trim();
    }

    if($(el).find('.ratings-metascore .mixed').length > 0){
      metascore[i] = $(el).find('.ratings-metascore .mixed').text().trim();
    }
  })
```

---

**Detailed explanations**

Let's say this you have this HTML

```html
<div class="a">
  <span class="b">hello</span>
  <span class="b">world</span>
</div>
```

and you run this javascript

```js
$(document).find('.a .b');
/**
* this code will return an Object like the following
* {
*   "0": span.b(DOM element)
*   "1": span.b(DOM element)
*   length: 2
* }
*/

$(document).find('.a .b').text();
/**
* this code will return a string like the following
* helloworld
*/
```

and if your run this one where you try to find the element `.a .c` which does not exists

```js
$(document).find('.a .c');

/**
* this code will return an Object like the following
* {
*   length: 0
* }
*/

$(document).find('.a .c').text();
/**
* this code will return an empty string, since no element was found
*/
```

So in both cases, the result of the `find()` is always an Object which is always **TRUE** in an `IF` statement, and since the `text()` always returns a **string** (an empty string when no element was found) that's why your second condition is always overriding the first one, because it's always true.

Comment: yes I understand how to get only the favorable reslts. However, what do you think I would need to do to get both the favorable and the mixed since I need both of these in the array

Comment: You just have to add .length > 0 to your if condition, see the code in the updated answer

Comment: I do not see where the updated answer is.

Comment: check now, it's in the Updated section, or refresh your page

Comment: It actuallly works. Thank you so much man, was stuck on this for too long. Can you just explain what adding .length > 0 does and why it works. Ik you answered it above but a detailed explanation would really help if possible

Comment: ok give me few minutes I will explain better

Comment: Does it basically mean that even though both return true, the .length > 0 is like a second test which actually tests if there actually is something there?

Comment: yes, and check the detailed answer I added, you will understand better

Comment: Thank you. It made perfect sense.

Comment: If this answer is correct please mark it as a solution so others can benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

You must make by the second if statement an else if, then it must function.
P.S.: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I did try an if else-if structure as well which does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshots i can tell that the element you are trying to find does not actually have both classes `ratings-metascore` and `mixed`. What you are doing is trying to access element by both the parent and child element properties, which should be done like so:

```
$('.ratings-bar').each((i, el) => {

  if($(el).find('.ratings-metascore > .favorable')){
    metascore[i] = $(el).find('.ratings-metascore > .favorable').text().trim();
  }

  if($(el).find('.ratings-metascore > .mixed')){
    metascore[i] = $(el).find('.ratings-metascore > .mixed').text().trim();
  }
})

console.log(metascore);
```

Comment: This does not seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to do that is:

```
metascore[i] = $(el).find('.ratings-metascore .favorable').text().trim() || 
  $(el).find('.ratings-metascore .mixed').text().trim()
```

Note that these will both evaluate to empty string if the element is not there, which is falsy in javascript:

```
let foo = "" || "bar"
// foo is now "bar"
```